# Random number generator with special condtition

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I have a 'not for the mark' question in  my assignment on Combinatorics, just to practice. I cannot figure it out.

The random generator generates $n$ numbers $k_1, \ldots, k_n$, where $k_i$ can take on values $0, \ldots, K$. Every time the sequence of $n$ numbers generated the sum of the elements in that sequence, $k_1+\ldots+k_n=K$.

1. Find how many different sequences would contain even number of odd numbers $k_i$; odd number of even numbers $k_i$?
2. How many sequences would contain even number of odd $k_i$ equal to each other?

I have started with just playing around with examples. The easiest is say, when $n=2$ and $K=2$, we have three possibilities for different sequences: $(2,0) (0, 2)$ and $(1,1)$. So, answer for Q1 would be: one sequence would contain even number of odd numbers $k_i=1$, i.e. $(1,1)$; and two sequences would contain odd number of even numbers $k_i=2$: $(0,2) (2,0)$.
For Q2: one sequence would contain even number of odd $k_i$ equal to each other--both $k_1=1$ and $k_2=1$ and its two of them in the sequence.

Now, I am not sure how to generalize this. I guess, I would have to split solutions for $K$ and $n$ being even and odd. I have tried for even cases, but still cannot see how to find a general solution.

Comment: Wouldn't $(0,2)$ contain an even number of even numbers?

Comment: $(0,2)$ would contain an odd number of even numbers. So, we are looking for the even number of even numbers per sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for your question is in this book: https://www.amazon.ca/Combinatorics-Compositions-Words-Silvia-Heubach/dp/1420072676 in Chapter 3 about compositions.